# Pygame game loop syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, pygame

I'm just doing some development in pygame and I've run into some very strange trouble. This is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

#Declarin some variables
WINHEIGHT = 320
WINWIDTH = 640
red = (255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((WINWIDTH, WINHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('My First PyGame')
FONT = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)

while True:

    pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAY, red, (100, 100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

I get an invalid syntax error on line 18 saying that

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
                               ^
```

Is a syntax error even though it isn't, help?

Answer (score 3):

Note the line above:

```
pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAY, red, (100, 100)
```

You are missing a parenthesis:

```
pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAY, red, (100, 100))
```

Comment: @NicholasWright Ha, don't - I'd be lying if I said I never got tripped up by that :)

Comment: If you're not using syntax highlighting, it helps with stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `)` in
Just put that
`(pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAY, red, (100, 100) # here!`

Comment: Your second line seems to be copied from your answer to another question, and this answer is just a duplicate of @RocketDonkey's from a week ago, isn't it?